# Consuming Rick and Morty's API in Spring Boot returns Null

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm trying to learn about API's in Spring Boot, and I'm struggling with the Rick and Morty API, when I give the getAllCharacters, the API returns all of the Characters with no problem, but, for example, when I try to retrieve just one Character (with the same logic, just changing the endpoint)

Service:

```
package com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.service;

import com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.pojo.Character;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    private static final String CHAHRACTER_API = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";

    @Override
    public Character getAllCharacter() {

        httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<Character> response = restTemplate.exchange(CHAHRACTER_API, HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, Character.class);

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.controller;

import com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.pojo.Character;
import com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.service.ApiService;
import com.burakkutbay.springbootresttemplateexample.service.ApiServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Character> getCharacters() {
        Character characters = apiService.getAllCharacter();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(characters, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

That code returns all the Characters, but, just to learn, if I tried to get to a specific character changing the `private static final String CHAHRACTER_API = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";` for `private static final String CHAHRACTER_API = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2";` in the service class, returns null

```
{
    "info": null,
    "results": null
}
```

¿Can anyone please explain why can retrieve many elements of the json but not one?

Thanks!

Comment: take another read at the docs. The JSON response in the two APIs are different, make sure you call or override the right method and read the right response from API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response of the api to get all characters is in this structure:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

```
{
    "info": {
    "count": 826,
    "pages": 42,
    "next": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
    "prev": null
    }
    "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Rick Sanchez",
      "status": "Alive",
      "species": "Human",
      "type": "",
      "gender": "Male",
      "origin": {
        "name": "Earth",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"
      },
      "location": {
        "name": "Earth",
        "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
      },
      "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg",
      "episode": [
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1",
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2",
        // ...
      ],
      "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1",
      "created": "2017-11-04T18:48:46.250Z"
    },
   ]
}
```

Whereas the JSON response of the api to get a single character has different structure:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Morty Smith",
  "status": "Alive",
  "species": "Human",
  "type": "",
  "gender": "Male",
  "origin": {
    "name": "Earth",
    "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"
  },
  "location": {
    "name": "Earth",
    "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"
  },
  "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/2.jpeg",
  "episode": [
    "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1",
    "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2",
    // ...
  ],
  "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2",
  "created": "2017-11-04T18:50:21.651Z"
}
```

As you can see there is no `"results"` Array object in the single-character JSON response.
So, you need to read the response accordingly.